# Oops, I think I managed to dispute my own flag!

Tags: support, bug, review, disputed-flags

So, funny story:

I was reviewing Late Answers earlier this week, and came across [this one](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/341029):

[image]

It looked more like a comment than an answer, but I wanted to see the other answer referenced here just to make sure. So, I navigated away to see the question and other answers. Once there, I saw what was up, and from the question page (not in the review queue) I flagged the answer as "Not an answer."

Then, I returned to the review queue. The `I'm Done` button was grayed out, so I clicked `flag` there, but it told me I'd already flagged the answer. The `I'm Done` button was still grayed out, so I opted to click `No Action Needed` thinking no harm would come from it since I had raised the flag.

Fast forward to today, and I saw my flag was disputed. I checked the review, and saw what is shown in the screen capture above. My "No Action Needed" vote cleared the answer from the queue.

I'm not positive about how this works, but I think my flag was auto-disputed by the answer passing the review queue unscathed. In which case, I disputed my own flag about 10 seconds after raising it.

So, two issues:

1. Can a moderator please take action on this non-answer?
2. Is self-disputing a feature or a bug? It seems like a bug to me. The appropriate site behavior would have been for the `I'm Done` button to be active because I had flagged the answer previously. Otherwise, this runs the risk of valid flags getting left in the wilderness.

Comment: (or a new tab...) ;p

Comment: Of course things work better when you do your reviewing *in* the Review Queue. But I've occasionally done what you did, and I seem to recall getting the "I'm Done" button to activate by refreshing the page.